# Is there an error in the datasheet for the SN74LS169B?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, logic-gates

I was looking at the TI SN74LS169B, a synchronous up/down binary counter.

Product page: https://www.ti.com/product/SN74LS169B

Datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/sn74ls169b

According to the datasheet:

> The direction of the count is determined by the level of the up/down input. When the input is high, the counter counts up; when low, it counts down.

However, I have been examining the functional logic diagram provided in the datasheet, and it seems to me that the behaviour should be the opposite. This is the functional logic diagram from the datasheet:

[image: functional logic diagram for SN74LS169B]

Assuming that Q is low for all the flip flops (the counter is at 0), LOAD is high to disable loading, ENP and ENT are low to enable counting, and U/D is high to set the counting direction to UP, I get the following result:

[image: functional logic diagram for SN74LS169B]

It looks like the inputs to the flip flops are all high, indicating that the next state of the counter would be 15, rather than 1.

Repeating the calculations for when U/D is low to set the counting direction to DOWN, I get the following result:

[image: functional logic diagram for SN74LS169B]

Now, it looks like the next state of the counter would be 1, rather than 15.

I have double, triple, and quadruple checked my work... is the counting direction backwards from what the datasheet indicates, suggesting an error in either the description or the logic diagram, or am I missing something??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't ever post on here - maybe I'll start more after this. When you ask TI to update a standard logic datasheet (like the [SN74LS169B](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74LS169B)), I'm one of the applications engineers that reviews, categorizes, and implements the fix.

Datasheets have errors because they are written by humans, and we (the humans that write them) always appreciate when people bring these errors to us. The best place to do this is on the [E2E support forums](https://e2e.ti.com/), which gives you a direct communication line to hundreds of applications engineers at TI. By entering the part number you are using when you make a post, the system will know exactly to which internal team to route your question.

In this case, I have opened a ticket in our internal datasheet error tracking system for me to review this logic diagram to verify the issue you have presented. Once I verify the issue (I have no reason to doubt your logic, so I'm assuming you are right), since this issue has a low impact on most customers, I will mark it as an update to be included when the datasheet is updated to the new standards.

I wanted to reply on here to let you know that you aren't being ignored, but this fix will likely take quite a while to be implemented due to our current workload and other tasks taking priority.

**Thank you for bringing this issue to my attention!**

Comment: I understand there will likely be a delay. In my simulation, I just swapped the U/D inputs on the AND gates, so all is well. I'm glad this issue will be reviewed and (eventually) implemented, though: it's nice to know TI is actually listening!